# Microcontroller interfacing

Tags: microcontroller, 8051

I am using 8051 micro controller kit which has 32 GPIO pins combined in 4 ports (8 pins for each port).

1. There is no dedicated ground pin for each port. Can I use ground from the supply side?
2. To give input as HIGH and LOW I have to give input voltage as 5V and 0V respectively. Do I need to worry about the current going in to these pins or just the voltage?

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use GND pin of micro controller to give LOW signal to any input Pin.
2. There is indeed a current limit. If you sink excess current in the input pin, you will end up frying the controller. Refer the datasheet to know these current limits.

Answer (score 0):

1) The microcontroller probably doesn't have separate grounds for the I/O and the power supply, so yes, but check the datasheet.

2) You just have to supply the required voltage and configure the required pin(s) as inputs.  Pull-up or pull-down resistors will be needed.  They may or may not be internal to the microcontroller for the port(s) that you plan to use.